# Meteor and multiple subscriptions to the same collection (and the same object)

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, meteor-publications

I am using meteor.js to write a large modular app. Inside my app, I have a collection named "Courses". The Schema of a object inside of the course collection looks like:

```
_id: MongoId
title: String
intro: String
content: Object
settings: Object
    secret: Object
    nonSecrets: Object
members: [Object]
    userId: MongoId
    wantsMail: Boolean
    gotMemberAt: Date
```

I have several Publications:

```
# Publish an overview of all courses, I am Member at
Meteor.publish 'myCourses', ->
     return Courses.find(
           {members:{$elemMatch:{userId: @userId}}},
           {fields:{title:1, intro:1, 'settings.nonsecret':1, 'members.$':1}}
     )

# Single Course Detail
Meteor.publish 'singleCourse', (id) ->
    return Courses.find(
        id, 
        {fields: {title:1, intro:1, content:1, 'settings.nonSecret':1}}
    )

# Admin Information of course
Meteor.publish 'singleCourseAdamin', (id) ->
    return Courses.find(
        id, 
        {fields: {title:1, settings:1, members:1}}
    )
```

My problem is now, that when I subscribe to all three publications, I don't get other members than those of the `myCourses` Publication.

Is there any good text about how publishing and subscribing to subsets of the same document work in actual meteor versions and what I need to check for if I want to make it work?

Or is there a package that make it easier to restrict the access to fields for each user?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/998). I recently added a section about it to [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) (see "Merge Box"). While there are some [complicated workarounds](https://medium.com/@MaxDubrovin/workaround-for-meteor-limitations-if-you-want-to-sub-for-more-nested-fields-of-already-received-docs-eb3fdbfe4e07), your best bet is to choose between:

1. Reorganizing your data so that sub-fields don't need to be published.
2. Only using one publisher at a time which needs a particular sub-field (in this case, maybe you could turn off the `myCourses` publisher when the admin publisher is active). This is probably hard to guarantee.
3. Just publish more data (the whole field). Obviously that may not work in some cases - particularly if there are security concerns.

Also note that you should have the same issue with the `settings` field when the first and last publisher are both active.

Comment: I found, that the problem is the 'members.$' operator that makes the pub/sub-system think that there is only this one element in the array. When I remove this part from the 'myCourses' publication, all the contents of the members array appears. Seems like I need another way of doing this.